# Implementing Java SDK in react native app

Tags: react-native

I am in the process of starting a new app development of android as a final project for school.

I would like to develop with React Native, but I must make sure it can be implemented with Java SDK.

Does it work? I see it is quite popular with the android studio to implement this SDK but couldn’t find any specific answer about implementation with react native.

Comment: Android Studio needs JavaSDK to run.... and this might help you: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app

Comment: Hi, thanks. The question is whether using React native will be able to implement JDK. I know that it is possible to implement it with Android studio.